# Not able to navigate to a route which has a redirectTo specified in Angular2 by name

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

My RouteConfig has the following paths defined

```
@RouteConfig ([
    { path:'/main',name:'Home',redirectTo: ['Setup']},
    { path:'/setup',name:'Setup',component:SetupComponent},
    { path:'/configuration',name:'Configuration',component:ConfigurationComponent},
])
```

In the template I have

```
    <ol>
        <li><a [routerLink]="['Setup']">Setup</a></li>
        <li><a [routerLink]="['Configuration']">Configuration</a></li>
        <li><a [routerLink]="['Home']">Home</a></li>                
    </ol>
```

In the component, in a method I have tried

```
this._Router.navigate(['Home']);
```

In both cases, (Using routerLink directive and Router.navigate method) when trying to navigate to 'Home' route, I am getting the following error.

```
Component "AppComponent" has no route named "Home"
```

Whereas both the routes which has a component associated to them are working as expected. The same is the behavior when they are invoked from Children routers.

How can I route/navigate to the route defined by the name 'Home'?

Comment: Is the `@RouteConfig` defined inside the AppComponent file?

Comment: @PierreDuc Yes, it is defined in AppComponent.

Answer (score 3):

You can't assign a name to a redirect route. Since `Home` redirects to the route named `Setup`, I'd use the `Setup` name instead.

Comment: I agree with you. You should treat the redirect route as a rule rather than a separate route.

Answer (score 0):

you should use / before router name this._Router.navigate(['/Home']);

see another example at [Routing through links in Angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48636813/routing-through-links-in-angular2/48636887#48636887)

Answer (score 0):

In your example code you have the home/main route object which is:

```
{
   path:'/main',
   name:'Home',
   redirectTo: ['Setup']
},
```

You need to route to the path - `/main` and not name - `Home`. So your html should be:

```
<ol>
   <li><a [routerLink]="'/setup'">Setup</a></li>
   <li><a [routerLink]="'/configuration'">Configuration</a></li>
   <li><a [routerLink]="'/main'">Home</a></li>
</ol>
```

Your TypeScript should be

```
this._Router.navigate(['/main']);
```

Also I don't see a `name` property in the [route interface](https://angular.io/api/router/Route) so do consider removing it.

Hope it helps.